# Existe alguma forma de fazer um tooltip padrão do navegador aparecer sem ser colocando o texto na tag title e sem plug-in de tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou perguntando isso pois a aplicação está quase pronta e utilizaram um plug-in que se utiliza da tag title. Esse plugin faz com que ao clicar no elemento se abra um popup(nesse caso uma caixa de confirmacao), com uma barra de titulo se utilizando do texto da tag title.

Porém ao usar a tag title esse plug-in remove a mesma do elemento, impossibilitando que ao passar o mouse por cima apareça o tooltip.

Comment: Modificar o plugin para que ele use outro atributo que não `title` seria uma solução viável?

Comment: Pensei nisso. Mas a principio não sei se seria o mais recomendado. É o popover do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na [página do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) é possível ler sobre a propriedade `data-title`:

> default title value if title attribute isn't present

O que significa:

> O valor do título se o atributo title não estiver presente.

Isso significa que uma solução seria adicionar o atributo `data-title` nos elementos que tiverem o *popover* com o mesmo valor do atributo `title`.

É possível fazer isso via javascript antes de chamar a função de inicialização. Exemplo:

```js
$(...)
  .each(function() { $(this).data('title', this.title) })
  .popover(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizar apenas CSS para a construção de Tooltips, dessa forma:

**CSS**

```css
*{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
div > .tooltip, li > .tooltip, a > .tooltip, span > .tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
}

  div:hover > .tooltip, li:hover > .tooltip, a:hover > .tooltip, span:hover > .tooltip,
  a .tooltip:hover, span .tooltip:hover, li .tooltip:hover, div .tooltip:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -40px;

    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  }

.tooltip {
  background: #3378C1;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -40px;

  position: absolute;

  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal; 

  z-index: 10;  
}

    .tooltip:before { /* Triangle */
      content: "";
      background: #3378C1;

      border: 0; 

      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 20px;

      display: block;
      position: absolute;

      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);


      display /*\**/: none\9;
      *display: none !important;
      *display: none;
    }


**HTML**
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
  <p>Este é exemplo demonstrativo de utilização de 
<a href="#"><strong>Tooltips</strong>
<span class="tooltip">
  Clique aqui e abra este link 
</span></a> 
e com isto fornecer mais uma ferramenta para seu website.</p>
```

Dê uma olhadinha no exemplo funciando [aqui](http://goo.gl/MoeUlT).

Comment: Nesse link so tem o resultado, coloque na sua resposta o código e de uma breve explicação, o stackoverflow funciona diferente de um forum, de uma olhada nessas orientações:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links/133

Comment: Desculpe-me pela ignorância, expus o mesmo exemplo no CodePen:
http://goo.gl/MoeUlT

Comment: Vi seu código e achei muito bom. Parabéns! No link o posicionamento da caixa com o tooltip não aparece em cima do conteúdo, ele está grudado na margem esquerda... isso não acontece com vc?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode customizar as opções quando inicializa o popover e voltar o atributo title pro valor original.

```
$('a').popover({
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
  content: function () {
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-original-title'));
      return $(this).text();
  },
  placement: 'auto right'
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilbarbara/6jd2U/